# Remove rows in a data frame that do not contain specific characters in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to remove rows in a dataframe that do not contain . or _

Basically, keep rows that have . or _

I've tried this with no luck: test = filter(test, grepl("_|.",V1)) where V1 is the name of the column

`test = filter(test, grepl("_|.",V1))`

For example, from "test", "test.com", "test_com", I'd like to keep "test.com" and "test_com" only.

Comment: `.` has a special meaning in regex, you need to escape it in `grepl`, Try `filter(test, grepl("_|\\.",V1))`

Comment: @RonakShah That worked perfectly, thanks! On a related note, how would I go about removing rows that end with .

Comment: I added an answer explaining that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` has a special meaning in regex, you need to escape it in `grepl`, Try

```
dplyr::filter(test, grepl("_|\\.",V1))

#         V1
#1  test.com
#2  test_com
#3 test.com.
```

---

To remove rows that end with `.` we can use

```
dplyr::filter(test, !grepl("\\.$", V1))

#        V1
#1     test
#2 test.com
#3 test_com
```

Or in base R

```
subset(test, !endsWith(V1, "."))
```

**data**

```
test <- data.frame(V1 = c("test", "test.com", "test_com", "test.com."),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```